# pip install tensorflow-data-validation fails on OS X El Capitan (10.11.6)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-data-validation

I am not able to install tensorflow-data-validation using pip. when I use:

`pip install tensorflow-data-validation`

I get this error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   tensorflow-data-validation

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Python 3? Because TensorFlow Data Validation currently requires Python 2.7.